# Filtering data on database level or application level

Tags: php, database

I have a database design where I have a Product which can have multiple properties. I am not so good in database design and that's why this question,

```
Product
------------------------------------
Id           Name         Model
------------------------------------
1            Galaxy S     GT-XX123
2            Galaxy Y     GT-YY123


Product Specifications
-------------------------------------
Spec         Value        ProductId
-------------------------------------
OS           Windows            1
Processor    Dual Core          1
Screen       3.5 Inch           1
OS           Android 4.1        2
Processor    Quad core          2
```

Now I would like to give user a facility to filter products on property basis, like OS = Android, Processor = Quad core. So my question is whether its a good idea to fetch data from database by writing complex query or its good to fetch data first and then filter data on application level?

**Edit**

I tried to create query by analysing each filter and then building a final query, but when multiple filters are applied in that case query doesn't work. The main problem I am facing is how can I select single record from two different values? so I am trying to solve that problem, meanwhile this question came to my mind so I asked, so instead of downvoting help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on how sophisticated your filters will be

Comment: There can be multiple filters those can be applied on the list like one for OS property, one for processor property and more..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I'd say if the filtering is easy in SQL definitely do the work there. Apart from anything else your SQL system is tuned to performing these actions (using INDEX etc.).

A second consideration is that if you send the entire dataset back to PHP that will need to be stored in memory whilst you loop through the data looking for your matches.

There are probably some circumstances, however, where the optimal solution is a half-way house where you do the highest level filtering in SQL then "fine tune" the results in the PHP.

Comment: What if nested number of nested sub queries are increasing more and more like in my case currently I am forming a subquery for each filter and those will increase if the number of filters applied are more?

Comment: Obviously there may come a point where the SQL code turns into the sort of tangled mess that is both a maintenance nightmare and also inefficient. At that time I think you've got to look at two things 1) is my database structure right? (Is there anything I can do to simplify the queries) and 2) is there a way to do most of the work in SQL before bringing the remaining data back for final filtering in the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a believer that the act of filtering is a business rule.  That being said I'm also a believer that business rules belong in application code not sql code.

Now that I've said that, let me give you my caveat:  you should try to never return more data from the database than you need.

So where's that leave us?  I'm not sure what technologies you're using (seems like it could be php which I have zero experience with), but if you have a good ORM that builds sql for you, you should be able to get the best of both worlds by abstracting your filter rules into your application logic and use them with your ORM to make sure you get exactly the right amount of data back from the database.

Good luck!

Comment: No I am not using any ORM, I am using php and plain mysql queries to fetch the data